# Irregular table vs borders along table headers

Tags: html, html-table, border

I have somehow similar table and all I want to do is to place the border along table headers as marked by red color on the screen.

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/xq4v.png/]

table shape is marked by black and I don't want this black borders to be visible.
I forgot to denote on this picture that some td's are also divided in half along the row.

I hope there is a better approach than to set borders to each individual td which I need.

Comment: That's what TH tags are for.

Answer (score 1):

If you give your table a class..

```
<table class='my-table'>
```

Then you can target all the td's in that class with css

```
.my-table td {
   border-left:1px solid red;
   border-right: 1px solid red;
}
.my-table {
   border-bottom: solid 1px red;
}
```

for the td's that are divided in half along the row, it may be easier to turn the borders off on those (maybe via inline styling), than it is to turn them on for all the other td's.  That is, if I am understanding what you're trying to do exactly.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is a combination of border-collapse and left right borders:

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Header One</th>
    <th>Header Two</th>
    <th>Header Three</th>
    <th>Header Four</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
    <td rowspan="4">Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
    <td>Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
    <td rowspan="3">Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
    <td>Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
    <td rowspan="4">Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
    <td rowspan="3">Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
    <td rowspan="2">Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sanctus sea sed takimata</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

With css:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table thead tr {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

table tbody {
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}

table tbody tr td {
    border-left: 1px solid blue;
    border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/PYWHA/

Comment: quite good, but my situation is more like http://jsfiddle.net/PYWHA/4/ t so your solution is not really adding borders along th